# Read Message With Empty RabbitMQ Payload

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I developed to monitor activity in rabbitmq such as user login, failed user login ,password create so on.
All of informations I need are listed in RabbitMQ header.

A delete event in rabbitmq comes as message like below.

Exchange    amq.rabbitmq.event
Routing Key user.deleted
Redelivered ●
Properties
timestamp:  1689743853
delivery_mode:  2
headers:
name:   TEST2
timestamp_in_ms:    1689743853594
user_who_performed_action:  TEST

Payload
0 bytes
Encoding: string

**When I read in my spring project, it throws this exception.
**

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1670)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1589)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1577)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:993)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:940)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1317)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1223)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Failed to convert Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:350)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:309)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.fromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:292)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:342)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter.extractPayload(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:366)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessagingMessageConverter.fromMessage(MessagingMessageConverter.java:132)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.toMessagingMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:243)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:146)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (String)""; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4765)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4667)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertBytesToObject(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:411)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.convertContent(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:378)
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.doFromMessage(AbstractJackson2MessageConverter.java:347)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Spring  version
<spring.boot.version>2.7.2</spring.boot.version>

How can I read empty payload without any converter failure in Spring Boot?

Kind Regards

Read rabbitmq message with empty payload without failure

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMessagaConverter resolved the problem. Instead of giving directly converter class, you can give MessageConverter class from configuration .

```
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
  factory.setMessageConverter(new SimpleMessageConverter());
```